# THERE ERROR IN MY Upload... error not all code returns a value

Tags: model-view-controller

```
public class Home : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Upload(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        if (Request != null)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["UploadedFile"];
            if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
            {
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                string fileContentType = file.ContentType;
                byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                var data = file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file.ContentLength));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>File:</td>
        <td>
            <input type="file" name="UploadedFile" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

Comment: Your need a `return` statement in your controller, e.g. `return RedirectToAction(....);`

Comment: at where can u pls specify

Comment: You could put it after your `if` block. I have no idea what you want to do after you execute your code - return the same view? redirect somewhere else?

Comment: Sir can u help me pls? i'm trying to read excel files and i'm stuck for days! can i contact u through ur mail or facebook?

Comment: Would really appreciate your help loads, please

Comment: @StephenMuecke sir??

Comment: I have already told you want you need to do!

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes sir but can u help me in my project? i need ur assistance

Comment: Help you with what? If you have another problem, then ask another question.

Comment: i cant make my mvc programme to make the import the excel sheet. googled codes all over the net but cant find. do u have any sample projects or codes for me?

Comment: @StephenMuecke help pls

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Upload(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    if (Request != null)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["UploadedFile"];
        if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
        {
            string fileName = file.FileName;
            string fileContentType = file.ContentType;
            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
            var data = file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file.ContentLength));
        }
    }

        return RedirectToAction("Index"); //Redirect to Action
 //        OR    

        return View(new ViewModel()); //ViewModel may your model class
}
```

**return View();** // <<< You need this return statement.

Comment: but hey can u help me in this project? can ive ur fb?

Comment: What kind of help, is ans helpfull for you?

Comment: do u hace fb or email so that i can send u?

Comment: would appreciate ur help

Comment: pls help me, add me in fb or email. i send u